# Get Reference to ILambdaContext in Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, aws-lambda

What's the best way to get a reference to the ILambdaContext in a Controller running in AWS Lambda ASP.NET Core?

It seems as though the below locks up.

```
(ILambdaContext)Request.HttpContext.Items[AbstractAspNetCoreFunction.LAMBDA_CONTEXT]
```

Answer (score 1):

The best I could figure out is to add a static member to the lambda entry point.

```
    public class AmazonLambdaEntryPoint : APIGatewayProxyFunction
{
    internal static ILambdaContext Context;

    

    public override async Task<APIGatewayProxyResponse> FunctionHandlerAsync(APIGatewayProxyRequest request, ILambdaContext lambdaContext)
    {
        Context = lambdaContext;
        return await base.FunctionHandlerAsync(request, lambdaContext);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem but was able to solve it by using the FunctionHandlerAsync override you have to access the StageVariables then storing it in an environment variable. Then from the Controller, I get that environment variable.

```
public override async Task<APIGatewayProxyResponse> FunctionHandlerAsync(
           APIGatewayProxyRequest request, 
           ILambdaContext lambdaContext)
{
        string environment = (request != null && request.StageVariables != null && request.StageVariables.ContainsKey("lambdaAlias")) ? request.StageVariables["lambdaAlias"] : "production";
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("lambdaAlias", environment);
        return await base.FunctionHandlerAsync(request, lambdaContext);
}

string environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("lambdaAlias");
```