# Access ILambdaContext in Lambda Entrypoint for dotnet serverless API

Tags: c#, .net, aws-lambda

Trying to get the ILambdaContext object - example and usecase below. I am using dotnet 6

```
 public class LambdaEntryPoint : Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.APIGatewayProxyFunction

    {
        internal static ILambdaContext Context;

        public override async Task<APIGatewayProxyResponse> FunctionHandlerAsync(APIGatewayProxyRequest request, ILambdaContext lambdaContext)
        {
            Context = lambdaContext;
            return await base.FunctionHandlerAsync(request, lambdaContext);
        }

        protected override void Init(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            var variables = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Context);
            //var variables = JsonConvert.Serliaze
            throw new Exception($"{variables}");
            var environment = "Beta";// arr[arr.Length - 1];


            //builder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((c, b) =>
            {
                b.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
                b.AddSystemsManager((source) =>
                {
                    var awsOptions = new AWSOptions();
                    awsOptions.Region = RegionEndpoint.EUWest1;
                    source.Path = $"/common";
                    source.AwsOptions = awsOptions;
                    source.ReloadAfter = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
                });
                b.AddSystemsManager((source) =>
                {
                    var awsOptions = new AWSOptions();
                    awsOptions.Region = RegionEndpoint.EUWest1;
                    source.Path = $"/{environment}";
                    source.AwsOptions = awsOptions;
                    source.ReloadAfter = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
                });
            }).UseStartup<Startup>();
        }
    }
```

I've used an example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65855061/get-reference-to-ilambdacontext-in-controller) to try override the FunctionHandlerAsync entrypoint but the Lambda context is null. I have also tried many other paths, all of which failed.

My goal is to get the alias from the lambda context to use as an environment configuration. I've read most of the internet and I am still unable to get this right.

Comment: What is the purpose of this lambda function? `Init` is called before `FunctionHandlerAsync` hence `context` is not available during `Init` method. That's why you are getting null? Can you explain what is the purpose of overriding Init method?

Comment: Is this your handler class?

Comment: If you are trying to run a web application using Lambda Function, then you need to understand that Lambda Functions are not for that purpose. Can you explain what exactly you are trying to achieve? @daveBM

Comment: @Chetan Init should get called after FunctionHandlerAsync as the handler is the entry point in the method. I have even tried serializing ILambdaContext to json and then printing it out but it is null in FunctionHandlerAsync method

Comment: @Chetan This is a stateless webapi that I have been running for a while in a Lambda. I basically am trying to get the alias of the function 

var arr = Context.InvokedFunctionArn.Split(':');
var env= arr[arr.Length - 1];

where InvokedFunctionArn is "arn:aws:lambda:Region:AccId:function:FunctionName:Production".
This function gets invoked by ApiGateway

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/operatorguide/static-initialization.html

Answer (score 0):

I have just tested this and your example works fine.

This was a .Net 6 "AWS Serverless Application" using "ASP.NET Core Web App".

The function handler override works and I can access the context.

Comment: Ok clarification here. The lambdaContext can be accessed in the FunctionHandlerAsync and I can successfully print out the AwsRequestId as an example. However, in the Init method the stored lambdaConext is null and I cannot seem to retrieve the AwsRequestId.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of:

```
ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, ILambdaContext>
```

To which you'll add in your lambda handler wrapper, and remove when the scope is over.

```
// MyLambdaWrapper.cs
using Amazon.Lambda.Core;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;

namespace MyNamespace;

public class MyLambdaWrapper
{
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, ILambdaContext> _contexts = new();

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddScoped(_ => new ScopeContextIdentifier(Guid.NewGuid()));
        services.AddScoped<ILambdaContext>(serviceProvider =>
        {
            var scopeContextIdentifier =
                serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ScopeContextIdentifier>();
            var contexts =
                serviceProvider
                    .GetRequiredService
                        <ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, ILambdaContext>>();
            var injected = contexts[scopeContextIdentifier.Guid];
            return injected;
        });
        services
            .AddSingleton<ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, ILambdaContext>>(_contexts);
    }

    public async Task Run
    (
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider, App app, Type handlerType
    )
    {
        Func<Stream, ILambdaContext, Task<Stream?>> func =
        async (inputStream, lambdaContext) =>
        {
            // ...
            using var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope();
            using var _ =
                new ScopeContextManager(scope, lambdaContext, _contexts);
            // ...
        };
        // ...
    }
}
```

and the manager:

```
// ScopeContextManager.cs
using Amazon.Lambda.Core;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;


namespace MyNamespace;

internal sealed record ScopeContextIdentifier(Guid Guid);

internal sealed class ScopeContextManager : IDisposable
{
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, ILambdaContext> _contexts;
    private readonly ScopeContextIdentifier _internalScopeContext;

    public ScopeContextManager
    (
        IServiceScope serviceScope,
        ILambdaContext lambdaContext,
        ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, ILambdaContext> ctx
    )
    {
        _internalScopeContext = serviceScope.ServiceProvider
            .GetRequiredService<ScopeContextIdentifier>();
        _contexts = ctx;
        _contexts.TryAdd(_internalScopeContext.Guid, lambdaContext);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _contexts.Remove(_internalScopeContext.Guid, out _);
    }
}
```